# Should my patio heater rod wobble?

Tags: heater, patio, propane

I am talking about a patio heater which looks something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/AZ-Patio-Heaters-48-000-BTU-Hammered-Bronze-Propane-Patio-Heater-HLDS01-CGT/205581273)

Now, it is operationally all fine and I have had no issues for last two years. However, when I touch the pole that the heater is on, it is not 100% unshakable. It is kind-of wobbly. I did search online to see if this is normal behavior but I did not come across anything with authoratitive anwser on this. I am just worried if I missed something during the assembly OR this is just normal behavior. Can anyone with similar patio heater share their experience as to what kind of sturdyness is expexted from this kind of patio heater?

Answer (score 1):

I have several of those patio heaters and all the assembly parts are very tight fit.  You should closely examine the connection joint and check for any bolts and screws that have loosen or missing.